# Working with several Generic parameters and multiple parent/child components in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, generics, components, blazor

I am brand new to Blazor and component-based frameworks and still very much a novice in C#. I am trying to make a table (which is a component called "Grid") that has multiple child components within it. Each column is its own component with header and footer components wrapped around it, which will later serve to help me sort, filter & sum each column, similar to Excel. For now I added some mock data in my Product class that is being stores in the `_products` List and I'm struggling to populate this table with the correct column names and row data. I was able to get the rows working with the correct data inside `<Columns>` I keep getting this error: `The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage` but the other examples on Stack Overflow for this error are too complex for me to follow along. Any advice would be amazing.

This is what's on my `index.razor` page:

```
<Grid Data="_products" Label="_columnNames" Options="@gridOptions" GetStyle="@(x => x.Name.EndsWith("1") ? "color: red" : null)">
<Headers>
    @foreach (var i in _columnNames)
    {
        <GridHeader Label="_columnNames[i]" />
    }        
</Headers>
<Columns>
    <GridColumn Value="@context.Id" />
    <GridColumn Value="@context.Name" />
    <GridColumn Value="@context.Weight" />
    <GridColumn Value="@context.Length" />
    <hr />
</Columns>
```

Here's all the parameters on this page

```
GridOptions gridOptions = new() { IsSelectionEnabled = true };
List<Product> _products = Product.InsertProductData().ToList();
List<string> _columnNames = new List<string>{ "ID", "Name", "Weight", "Length" };
```

This is my Grid component called `Grid.razor`:

```
@typeparam T

<div class="mb-3">
    
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            @if (Label != null)
            {
                @foreach (var item in Label)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @Headers
                    </tr>
                }
            }
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @if (Data != null)
            {
                @foreach (var model in Data)
                {
                    <tr style="@GetStyle(model)">
                        <th scope="row">
                            @Columns(model)
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

And these are the parameters on my Grid component where the generics are being used:

```
[Parameter] public ICollection<T> Data { get; set; }

[Parameter] public ICollection<T> Label { get; set; }

[Parameter] public GridOptions Options { get; set; }

[Parameter] public RenderFragment Footer { get; set; }

[Parameter] public RenderFragment<T> Columns { get; set; }

[Parameter] public RenderFragment Headers { get; set; }

[Parameter] public Func<T, string> GetStyle { get; set; }
```

I think the issue is with the `Headers` RenderFragment because it was working before I added this code, but now even when I comment that out it's not working so I'm confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you need to specified the param type to the component

```
<Grid Data="_products" T="Product" ...
```

But I see a lot of errors in your code here I did a similar working example ...

```
<Grid Data="_products" T="Product" Label="_columnNames" H="string" GetStyle="@(x => x.Name.EndsWith("1") ? "color: red" : null)">
    <Headers>
        <div>@context</div>
    </Headers>
    <Columns>
        <td>@context.Id</td>
        <td>@context.Name</td>
        <td>@context.Weight</td>
        <td>@context.Length</td>
        <hr />
    </Columns>
</Grid>

@code
{
    record Product(int Id, string Name, int Weight, int Length);
    List<Product> _products = new()
    {
        new Product(1, "San", 80, 177),
        new Product(2, "Luli", 64, 168)
    };
    List<string> _columnNames = new List<string>{ "ID", "Name", "Weight", "Length" };

}
```

and the grid ...

```
@typeparam T
@typeparam H

<div class="mb-3">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        @if (Label != null)
        {
            <tr>
            @foreach (var item in Label)
            {
                <th>
                    @Headers(item)
                </th>
            }
            </tr>
        }
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @if (Data != null)
        {
            @foreach (var model in Data)
            {
                <tr style="@GetStyle(model)">
                        @Columns(model)
                </tr>
            }
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

@code
{
    [Parameter] public ICollection<T> Data { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public ICollection<H> Label { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment Footer { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<T> Columns { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<H> Headers { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public Func<T, string> GetStyle { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! My understanding of using generic parameters in C# is still so new, I didn't realize I needed to declare a new generic param to pass in different object types. This also helped me understand another error I kept getting when I didn't declare `RenderFragment<H>` for the `Headers` component (an error I was also getting for the `Columns` component for the longest time -- so if I'm passing in data of type <H> the RenderFragment also needs to be able to accept type <H> right? Thank you!!

Comment: Exactly, I'm glad to help